# Zynga Fontlabel is accepted by AppStore?

Tags: ios, fonts, runtime

I need to handle fonts in iOS at runtime. The only solution I found is zynga FontLabel: https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel.

I am not sure, if using this solution, will affect the acceptance of my App into AppStore. So my question is, will using this solution ruin my chance of getting my App into AppStore? Any experience with that?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FontLabel will *not* prevent you from getting listed on the app store. It doesn't use any private frameworks or alone violate any App Store policies.

Many apps use it on the App Store today without an issue.